# How to display all outlet at the product page and assign product to specific outlet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m new in Ruby on Rails, what I’m doing is a grocery shop website. The company have many outlets and products.

An admin can add a product and outlet, there can be different products and outlets, each outlet can have the same product but not the same price (Example outlet A and B have fish but A is $5 but B is $6)

The Admin can select and choose to assign an item to an outlet and edit the price, the final result will be stored in the `OutletProduct` table.

Below is what I have done but it doesn't work and shows an error.

Product Controller Code:

```
def outlet
@outlet = Outlet.find(params[:id])
end

def add
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@outlet = Outlet.find(params[:outlet_id])
end

def update
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
@outlet = Outlet.find(params[:outlet][:name])
if @product.update(product_params)
  flash[:success] = "Product updated"
  redirect_to @product
else
  render 'add'
 end
 end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @product.name)%>

<%= render @product %>
 <div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
   <section class="stats">
    <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
   </section>
   <div>
   <%= link_to "Add to Outlet", add_path %> |
   <%= link_to "Back to products", products_path %>
  </div>
</aside>
</div>
```

add.html.erb

```
<h1>Add to outlet</h1>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <%= form_with(model: @product, local: true) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :quantity %>
  <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.number_field :price, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :outlet %>
  <%= f.select :outlet, options_for_select(@outlets), :include_blank => true %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :category_id, value: 1 %>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Product Migration Table Code:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
   create_table :products do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.integer :quantity
   t.integer :price
   t.integer :category_id

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

[Error shown in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Nsf.png)

[Error shown in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6dxo.png)

[After add-outlet clicked (in console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikkjY.png)

[The page after clicked Add Outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPM1.png)

UPDATE

[Error shown in website after made changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci90t.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ProductsController for action `add`, it is erroring out because `params[:id]` and `params[:outlet_id]` are nil.

In show.html.erb `<%= link_to "Add to Outlet", add_path %>` it is linking to add_path but does not specify what the value of `id` or `outlet_id` should be.

Try changing it to `add_path(@product)` or `add_path(id: @product.id)`

For `outlet_id`, it looks like this may not be needed, instead you may want to change the add action to return a list of outlets:

```
def add
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @outlets = Outlet.all
end
```

UPDATE

The new error is telling you that the `outlet object` does not have a method called `outlet`. This is caused by: `Outlet.all.collect { |l| [l.outlet, l.id] }`. You can use `l.name` instead of `l.outlet`.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your answer but how about the add.html.erb form select outlet there, it return me some error , I will show the error at the post

Comment: updated answer!

Comment: Thanks so much Joe, it works!!! I still have a questions is what did i need to do if i want the result is store at OutletProduct table there